# How to translate 'field_vote'?

Tags: i18n-l10n, rating

I have installed [Fivestar](https://drupal.org/project/fivestar) module on D7 and tried to translate 'fied_vote'. But the string can not be found in the translation interface at admin/config/regional/translate/translate. 
So wondering how to translate it?